# Why my nested ifelse is not working properly in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a `data frame` and I am trying to create a `new column` based on `another column's value` condition. The `first 4 ifelse` is working fine but `later 3 ifelse` is not working. Also not showing any errors.

I am not sure how to write ifelse condition for the `character type factor` column.

The code is given below

```
data$Region <- ifelse(data$Station.Names == "Bogra" | data$Station.Names == "Dinajpur" | data$Station.Names == "Rangpur" | data$Station.Names == "Syedpur", "Northern Region",
                  ifelse(data$Station.Names == "Rajshah", "Northwestern Region",
                         ifelse(data$Station.Names == "Satkhira" | data$Station.Names == "Khepupara" , "Northsouthern Region",
                                ifelse(data$Station.Names == "Dhaka" | data$Station.Names == "Tangail" | data$Station.Names == "Mymensingh", "Central egion",
                                       ifelse(data$Station.Names == "Comilla" | data$Stations.Names == "Feni" | data$Stations.Names == "Maijdee-Court" | data$Stations.Names == "Madaripur", "Southern Region",
                                              ifelse(data$Station.Names == "Chittagong (IAP-Patenga)" | data$Station.Names == "Sitakunda" | data$Station.Names == "Teknaf", "Southeastern Region",
                                                     ifelse(data$Station.Names == "Sylhet" | data$Station.Names == "Srimangal", "Eastern Region", "NAA")
                                              )
                                       )
                                )
                         )
                  )
```

)

Any kind of guidelines is appreciated.

Comment: If you are allowed to use `dplyr` and/or `tidyverse` I would strongly recommend using the `case_when` instead of a nested if statement. `case_when` is much easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you have written two types of `data$station.Name` and `data$Stations.Name`

Maybe this is the problem! Do changes and let me know!